# navLinkDayClick of FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Did anyone use navLinkDayClick of FullCalendar and call a custom event (by fetching data from database) based on the date selection?

I am using eventClick to populate the calendar data however I am unable to do so for individual dates after setting the navLinks to true.

Everything above navLinkDayClick works fine.

```js
function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {method contains to fetch all event from database}

function FetchTotalAmount() { method calls a SP to get the total amount for that day of the calendar}. This also contains the method to generate the calendar which is given below.

function GenerateCalender(events) - events are the ones that are fetched in the first method.

function GenerateCalender(events) {
..................
..................
events: events,
eventClick: function (calEvent) {
var selectedCalendarEvent = calEvent;
$('#calendarModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.title);
..................
..................
navLinks: true,
navLinkDayClick: function() {
how to use this to show the total amount for that day of the calendar when the date is selected?
}
```

Comment: `(by fetching data from database) based on the date selection`...why would you want to do that?? If you already implement a proper event feed (e.g. via https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) then fullCalendar will automatically request the right event data for the time period being displayed on the calendar, without needing any further intervention.

Comment: I am generating the calendar properly and it is initially fetching all the events correctly and showing it properly in the Calendar UI.

What I am trying to do here is that I am trying to show different result set based on certain calculation in the navlink. Now, I am unable to understand how to pass those different events.

I have already used eventClick and events to render the calendar with the initial requirement/events but I am unable to do so for the second requirement/events.

For both the different requirements, I am using different modals to show the data.

Comment: `trying to show different result set based on certain calculation`...and what calculation is that exactly? In the question you said it's based on date, but as I stated above, fullCalendar can already handle fetching events based on date, in a much better way, if you provide it with an event feed (rather than just a static list of events).

Comment: My first requirement is to fetch all the events based on different dates and my second requirement is to show the summation of data based on different dates.

For my first req., I am using eventClick and events and then when that particular event is clicked, a modal opens up showing all the data of that date. A particular date can have multiple events.

But for my second req., I am trying to use navLink so that on clicking on the day of the month, it can show the summation for all the data of that day.

After fetching data for both reqs., I am generating the calendar.

Comment: `I am trying to use navLink so that on clicking on the day of the month, it can show the summation for all the data of that day`...ok. So where exactly are you stuck with that? You can specify a custom callback function to be run when the link is clicked, as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/navLinkDayClick . But `fter fetching data for both reqs., I am generating the calendar` ...doesn't seem to make much sense. The calendar is already generated when that link is clicked. Are you saying you want to put more events into the calendar at that time? Maybe giving some worked examples would help us

Comment: Yes, you are right. I can use custom callback function but how do I pass the data as event to the navlinkdayclick so that once that day is selected (suppose say 22nd December, 2022), the summation data is show in another modal.

I am assuming that clicking the date (22nd December, 2022) is actually an event. Is there any other way rather than event to show the data when the date is clicked.

Different methods are used to fetch different data-set. I am able to render the first dataset as events and eventClick but failing for the second data-set.

I will try to share some images of it.

Comment: Don't share images unless they are screenshots of the actual calendar. If you want to show code, please show it as text. Either way please [edit] your post to include all this important information and [format it nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - Stackoverflow is not a discussion forum really...the comments are just to ask briefly for clarification or small pieces of info. See also [ask] and the [tour] please, so you understand how the site works :-).

Comment: `I am assuming that clicking the date (22nd December, 2022) is actually an event`...it's not really clear what you mean by this. Are you asking how to get all the events which occur on that date? It would certainly help a lot if you show your current code (including any attempt to implement your requirement), show some sample event data, and show exactly what result you want to get from clicking on the nav link. It's a lot easier to understand actual code and data, than to understand just descriptions of it.

Comment: I have added the code snippet. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: I've already listed what additional information is useful - see my last comment

Comment: Also, can you confirm exactly what version of fullCalendar you're using? You've tagged it with v5, but the very-minimal code provided so far suggests you might actually be using v3? There are significant differences between the two.

Comment: `how to use this to show the total amount for that day of the calendar`...total amount of what? And from where is that information coming? Please always be clear, specific and detailed. Remember we cannot see your screen, look at your files, or read your mind. We know _nothing_ about your application, your data, or your requirements except what you tell us here. If you tell us vague things, we can't give clear answers.

Comment: It is fullcalendar-3 and not v5. I am not sure how it got tagged.
Total amount is the sum/count of all the events happening on that particular day. It is coming from the database via a different function.

Comment: Ok thanks. Any reason you use such an old version? fullCalendar 6 is just released. It's faster, has more features, and less bugs, and doesn't require jQuery. But if you want to stick with v3 for some reason, you can use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/clientEvents to get all events currently visible in the calendar, and there's an option to set a callback to filter them, so you can filter them by date quite easily, and then sum the total. As you can see navLinkDayClick (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/navLinkDayClick) provides you with the date which was clicked.

Comment: Obviously if you prefer to get them from the server, you'll need an AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks ADyson. I was making it a way more complicated. I have used the navLinkDayClick and passed the date and thereafter could get the summation based on individual dates.

Comment: OK great. You should put your code in an answer below, with a short description, in case anyone else with a similar idea finds it useful. Then they can find it in searches and vote on it.

Comment: I have added the code snippet above. Thanks.

Comment: No, I said **below**, in the Answers section, not above. The answer is not part of your question!! Please take the [tour] if you don't understand how stackoverflow's question and answer format works. Right now, no-one can search for your answer or give you votes for it, because you hid it inside the question. And as far as the search engine is concerned,  the question still has no recorded answers.

Comment: My bad ADyson! I have placed my answer in the correct place now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

navLinkDayClick in FullCalendar v3.8 -

```js
navLinks: true,
navLinkDayClick: function (date) {
selectedDate = date.format("DD-MMM-YYYY");
selectedAmountEvent = amounts.find(item => item.paymentDate.format("DD-MMM-YYYY") === selectedDate);
var $AmountData = $('<div/>');
$AmountData.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Payment Date: </b>' + selectedAmountEvent.paymentDate.format("DD-MMM-YYYY")));
if (selectedAmountEvent.totalAmount < 0) {
    $AmountData.append($('<p/>').html('<b style="color:red;">Total Amount: ' + selectedAmountEvent.totalAmount + ' $' + '</b >'));
}
else {
    $AmountData.append($('<p/>').html('<b style="color:green;">Total Amount: ' + selectedAmountEvent.totalAmount + ' $' + '</b >'));
}
 
$('#eventModal #AmountDetails').empty().html($AmountData);

$('#eventModal').modal();
}
```

amounts is an array holding the data.